# Big source / minified files make Chrome Developer Tools freeze

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Opening big JavaScript files, such as minified files on Chrome Developer Tools, tab Sources, makes it freeze. On a project of mine, if I click on `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` it hangs and I can't do anything other then close the tab. To make things even harder, Chrome remembers the last file opened on the Source tab, and remembers the last tab opened, so I have to open another website, fire up Developer Tools and change tabs in order to make it work on my project. I had to debug using Firefox instead of Chrome.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a known bug: [Chromium Bug Tracker - Issue 593679 - [REGRESSION] DevTools: Big sources hang the Developer Tools](https://crbug.com/593679), and it's currently fixed, but not available on regular/stable Google Chrome or Chromium.

The temporary solution is to use [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html).

Comment: If you're visiting this issue in 2018, it's a newer bug being tracked [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=751763).

Comment: And if you're visiting in 2020, supposedly this issue was just fixed!  It's available in Chrome 84, which in May 2020 means you need to use Chrome Canary.

Comment: It is still broken in 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable).

Comment: Still hanging in 2021

Comment: Still hanging in 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: still hangs (Version 103.0.5060.114)

Comment: Still hangs on version 111.0.5563.146

Answer (score 9):

For me blackboxing is not working also. Helps only:

1. Kill Chrome process that eats CPU (developer tools will be closed)
2. Open any website without huge source files (e.g. ya.ru)
3. Switch source tab to another
4. Open Developer Tools on the target website (and do not switch to source tab)

Also I do not have this problem on Chrome Canary

Comment: Yeah, the problem has been solved recently on Chrome Canary. I'll edit my post to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you for this workflow, getting Dev tools.to unfreeze is such a pain.

Answer (score 9):

> Chrome remembers the last file opened on the Source tab

This is how I worked around that, and got my sources tab back:

1. Open devtools on a site other than the one that hangs it
2. Ctrl + Shift + I to inspect the devtools itself
3. Go to the Application tab then Local Storage
4. Locate the `previouslyViewedFiles` key under `devtools://devtools`
5. Press the delete key to delete the entry

Comment: Wow.  This is really useful.  Never realized you can open devTools for devTools. Thanks so much for this.  I was having a hard time getting devTools back up after attempting to open a very large minified javascript file.

Comment: Agreed, not only was this very helpful, but also very eye opening in the sense that you can run devTools on devTools.  So cool!!!!

Answer (score 6):

**Update Sept 2020:**

Just coming back to note that I tested Chrome stable 85.0.4183.121, and this is much improved! (I haven't tested in a while, so I'm not sure exactly when it improved. But there was some movement on the [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=751763) in May.)

[image]

**Sept 2019:** Chrome 77 still has this problem.

Here's [one way](https://i.imgur.com/XqiE4gZ.mp4) it happens:

1. Open page, open debug tools
2. Open your desired minified JS file, click the pretty format button.
3. Set two breakpoints on line N and line N+1
4. Refresh your browser. Hits first breakpoint quickly.
5. Press resume / F8
6. Takes 2 minutes to reach the next breakpoint.

Here's [another way](https://i.imgur.com/QEL1wNl.mp4) it happens:

1. Open page, refresh a few times, all good
2. Open debug tools, find file, pretty print
3. Refresh a few times, still good
4. Try to add a breakpoint in pretty formatted file...
5. FREEZES, cpu pegged, can't click
6. 140 sec later, tools responsive again

Answer (score 4):

Pretty printing the minified file (in the debugger, by klicking the {} button) seems to "solve" this (version 51.0.2704.103 m). Chrome will initially slow to a crawl, but click and give it a good number of seconds and it will calm down a soon as the pretty printed source is displayed.

Comment: This isn't really useful as the window is still frozen while loading the file. Pretty printing the file requires the content to be loaded surely?

Comment: @JohanAspeling: For me it works albeit very slowly (as stated). The file must be loaded for the code to execute (and fail) so I assume what takes time is the pretty printing process not (re)loading a file which is in memory already.

Answer (score 0):

For me, my browser wasn't freezing until I tried to save a change to a large, minified JS file in the `sources` panel. Chrome Canary wasn't solving this problem for me like it had for others, but I was able to find a solid work around by using the "Local Overrides" feature in Chrome Dev Tools. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides

Chrome still crashed when I saved a change in dev tools to a javjascript file in the sources tab, but it did successfully save it to the overrides folder and i was able to see this change on my site after reloading Chrome.